# Rails: Field was defined as a(n) Array, but received a ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I've created a Post and a TagObject model as follows

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  embeds_many :tag_objects

  #embeds_many :comments

  references_one :uploader, :class_name => 'User'
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  validates_presence_of :image

  attr_accessible :tag_objects, :image
end

class TagObject
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  field :tags, :type => Array

  embedded_in :post, :inverse_of => :tag_objects

  attr_accessible :name, :tags
end
```

and currently have a page submit a PUT to the update method of the Post controller. The update fails and I get the following in the WEBrick console.

```
Started POST "/posts/4d4a174fa729cf71c70000a8" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Feb 02 21:52:09 -0500 2011
  Processing by PostsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"post"=>{"tag_objects"=>{"1"=>{"tags"=>{"1"=>"testingfds"}}}}, "authenticity_token"=>"OZ+eXzD5NyqUI4CzPadlFUMDwRrg4LsaQBs5i+J65tU=", "id"=>"4d4a174fa729cf71c70000a8"}
honeycomb_development['posts'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4d4a174fa729cf71c70000a8')}, {}).limit(-1)
Completed   in 2ms

Mongoid::Errors::InvalidType (Field was defined as a(n) Array, but received a ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess with the value {"1"=>"testingfds"}.):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:39:in `update'
```

I have absolutely no idea how to fix it and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You know, I hit this last week. Unfortunately I don't remember what the solution was, but rest assured, it's here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yah, seems the problem was that it was trying to do

```
tags = {0=>'testingdfg'}
```

instead of doing

```
tags[0] = 'testingdfg'
```

and set it's contents like I was expecting. I just added some logic into the update method to do so, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In the model, put

```
field :tags, :type => Hash
```

instead of

```
field :tags, :type => Array
```